# How to access/share datasets from different Colab notebooks

Tags: python, variables, jupyter-notebook, dataset, google-colaboratory

I want to plot graphs that share variables and datasets from other CoLab files, I would like to know how I could access those variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new folder 'VARIABLES' where the variables are saved, read, and re-written (i.e. updated) as txt or csv files. Otherwise, defining a variable in one Colab Notebook will only be accessible within that Colab Notebook and not between Colab Notebooks.